# Лучший способ понять, что объект - не массив и не скаляр

Tags: javascript

Есть ли на данный момент более оптимальный способ понять, что объект - не массив и не скаляр? В настоящий момент использую такую конструкцию:

```js
const check = (item) => !Array.isArray(item) && item instanceof Object;

console.log(check({a: {b: "c"}}));      // object   - true
console.log(check(["a", "b", "c"]));    // array    - false
console.log(check("строка"));           // string   - false
console.log(check(100500));             // number   - false
console.log(check(true));               // boolean  - false
console.log(check(null));               // null     - false
console.log(check(function() {}));      // function - true
```

UPD: Добавил больше типов. Выяснилось, что `function` эта конструкция проверяет некорректно.

Comment: Зачем `instanceof Object`? Вы ещё и скаляры обрабатываете?

Comment: @vp_arth всё верно, исправил вопрос. Хочется оптимизировать условие.

Comment: что такое "скаляр"?

Comment: скалярные типы: string, boolean, number, 
составные типы: object, array, function

Comment: @Grundy, литерал?

Comment: @renich, `new String('string') instanceof Object -> true`

Comment: @Grundy в моём случае это не требуется, так как данные на входе ограничиваются строками, массивами и объектами. Но было бы интересно закрыть все варианты. Что касается литералов, то для меня это как "значение типа", то есть, например, литералы для `boolean` это `true` и `false`, а не `1` и `0` (но это неточно).

Comment: @Grundy, скаляр в js - это «не объект»

Comment: @vp_arth, первый раз такой термин встречаю применительно к js

Answer (score 4):

Всё у вас ок. Вам же нужно убедиться, что объект не скаляр и не массив.
Ровно это Вы и проверяете.

Если скаляров не будет, проверку на объект можно опустить.

```js
const check = a => 
  (typeof a === 'object' && a !== null) 
    && !Array.isArray(a)

console.log(check({a: {b: "c"}}));      // object   - true
console.log(check(["a", "b", "c"]));    // array    - false
console.log(check("строка"));           // string   - false
console.log(check(100500));             // number   - false
console.log(check(true));               // boolean  - false
console.log(check(null));               // null     - false
console.log(check(function() {}));      // function - false
```

Comment: Да, проверка на объект меня нужна для переменных любого типа. Использую способ из вопроса, но надеялся что уже это осовременилось во что-то более компактное.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.isObject = () => false
Object.prototype.isObject = () => true

[1,2,3].isObject() // false
```

Comment: Жду когда кто-то напишет изъяны этого варианта, кроме как, что у объекта прототип может быть прототипом Array, и соответственно метод этого объекта `isObject()` будет выдавать `false`.

Comment: @entithat Может наведете пример?

Comment: Не знаю, будет ли кто-то так писать на практике, но даже `let a = {}; Object.setPrototypeOf(a, Array.prototype); a.isObject(); // => false`. Но как по мне, это интересный вариант.

Comment: @entithat Окей, встечный вопрос, зачем тогда различать объект от массива, когда вы пользуетесь практикой подмены прототипа?

Comment: Это уже зависит от нужд автора, я чисто привёл пример, когда такой вариант, возможно, не заработает.

Comment: Проблема расширения встроенных прототипов только в том, что это может сделать каждый, и не исключено, что может попасться точно такая же функция `isObject` - которая бы работала совсем по другому, и никто об этом бы не узнал

Comment: Пардоньте, исправил вопрос - объект нужно отличать не только от массива, но и от скаляра. По этому `"строка".isObject()` даст `true` в данном случае.